# SQL function to return formatted list of phone numbers

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-function

Looking to build an SQL Server function that pulls a list of phone numbers from a table and formats them in a specific way so that they can be passed into a paging systems API.

The value returned could contain any number of phone numbers and each one needs to be wrapped in double quotes and separated by a comma.

The following function:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @MyRESULT varchar(max)
DECLARE @PAGING_RESULTS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT PHONE_NUMBER FROM CONTACTS WHERE ON_CALL = 1
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @MyRESULT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Set @PAGING_RESULTS = isnull(@PAGING_RESULTS, '') + '"%2B' + isnull(@MyRESULT, '') +  '",'
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @MyRESULT
END
Close MyCursor
deallocate MyCursor
Set @PAGING_RESULTS = isnull(@PAGING_RESULTS, '')
return @PAGING_RESULTS
END
```

Is getting me close but it leaves me with an extra comma at the end of result that breaks the API call.

Is there a better way I can do this or additional work I can do in the function to clean the results.

Sample data:

| Phone | On Call |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | 1 |
| 9876543210 | 1 |
| 7652341890 | 1 |

Ideal result:

"1234567890", "9876543210", “7652341890”

The current function does return my result set but there is an extra / invalid comma at the end, for example:

"1234567890", "9876543210", “7652341890”,

Many thanks!

Comment: Show sample data and desired results, its very unlikely you need a loop for a simple update.

Comment: Sure thing. For this purpose the data can be assumed to be a simple 2 column table, column A contains the phone numbers and column B contains the flag for if that phone number should be paged , i.e., 1234567890 | 1 or 19876543210 | 1. The results set would "%2B1234567890", "%2B19876543210"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursors are slow, don't use them for simple things.

EDIT: As some people said, don't use this "clever" way, due to unexpected results possible:

```
-- DECLARE @MyRESULT varchar(max)=''
-- SELECT @MyRESULT = @MyRESULT + '"%2B' + ISNULL(PHONE_NUMBER, '') +  '",'
-- FROM CONTACTS WHERE ON_CALL = 1
-- RETURN LEFT(@MyRESULT,LEN(@MyRESULT)-1)
```

When your MSSQL version is 2017 or higher:

```
DECLARE @MyRESULT VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @MyRESULT = STRING_AGG('%2b"'+PHONE_NUMBER+'"',',')
FROM CONTACTS WHERE ON_CALL=1
```

Source code of STRING_AGG is avaliable in the internet, so - it is possible to implement own string_agg or just use FOR XML.

Comment: No string_agg sadly but your first option did what I needed! Thank you for showing me a faster and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Not recommended to use the first version, it's undefined behaviour, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment. And `RETURN` can only use an `int` value, it's intended for status codes only.

Comment: Hmm .. indeed. I've been using it for twenty years with no problems :-) Time for changes, it is so much easier that I said goodbye to SQL 2008 some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a fully supported version of SQL Server simply use `string_agg()`

```
select @Result = String_Agg(Concat('"', phone, '"'), ', ')
from Contacts
where on_call = 1;
```

On version 14 and prior you can use `for xml path`, and `stuff` removes the additional delimiter.

```
select @Result = Stuff(
(
    select ', ' + Concat('"', phone, '"')
    from Contacts
    where on_call = 1
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: Sadly string_agg() is not supported in my version. Thank you for XML_PATH option.

Comment: @andrew.reynolds81 THen the for xml path is the solution you should use, not the solution in the other answer; you should *not* be aggregating strings by concatenating them into a variable, it's even specifically pointed out not to do so in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)